# link in body of Email Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to send in the body of my Email a link, i have this in my controller .

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                                    ->setSubject('demande de conge ')
                                    ->setFrom($col->getEmailCollaborateur())
                                    ->setTo($form->get("emailcdp")->getData())
                                    ->setBody($this->render('MytestBundle:Conge:demandeCongeNormal.html.twig', array('conge' => $conge)))
                                    ;
                                    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

in my demandeCongeNormal.html.twig:

```
  <a href={{ conge.justificatif}}>confirmer</a>
```

in the Email that i receive i have :

```
  <a href=lllllllll>confirmer</a>
```

i'm new in Symfony please any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `url` function in twig template. For example:

```
<a href="{{ url('_your_route_name_to_active', {'route_parameter': 'route_parameter_value'}) }}">Activate</a>
```

`_your_route_name_to_active` is a defined route from `app/config/routing.yml` or from `AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

Example:

```
_acmebundle_signup_confirm:
    pattern:  /confirm/{user}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Index:confirm }
    requirements:
        user:  \d+
```

Where is `route_parameter` equals to `user` parameter in requirements.

For more information about routing, please read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: please can u explain me what's : _your_route_name_to_active,route_parameter,route_parameter_value and additional_parameter!!!

Comment: @DmitriiKorotovskii Can you please show me how to pass two  parameters to route_parameter?